# Joomla - Multiple primary key equivalent to JTable bind override for ACL

Tags: php, joomla

I have the following code in a JTable bind method override:

```
if(!JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.admin', 'com_escorders.audittrail.'.$array['id'])){
    $actions = JFactory::getACL()->getActions('com_escorders','audittrail');
    $default_actions = JFactory::getACL()->getAssetRules('com_escorders.audittrail.'.$array['id'])->getData();
    $array_jaccess = array();
    foreach($actions as $action){
        $array_jaccess[$action->name] = $default_actions[$action->name];
    }
    $array['rules'] = $this->JAccessRulestoArray($array_jaccess);
}
```

This works without issue when the primary key is `id` but I want to modify this code for a table with multiple keys. What do I need to replace `array['id']` with assuming the keys are `key1` and `key2`?

Comment: So you are using something as an asset that has multiple keys? What structure for asset names are you using when you save in your table class You seem to be saying it is saved as 'com_escorders.audittrail.'.$array['id']  but it needs to be saved as a string ... so I'm a bit puzzled ... shouldn't you be imploding the array or something like that? It's definitely a cool use case to be trying but I think you need to deal with that.

Comment: @Elin Thanks for the reply! I have to admit I'm not really clear on the function of this code as it is from a component made with component-creator.com but it was throwing an error when I modified the table to use multiple keys. I'm trying to create an audit trail for changes to a particular table but I think I'm overly complicating things. I've given up on the multiple keys idea and trying a different approach. Any experience with audit trails?

Comment: Oh, so what you were trying is pretty advanced, when you use one of those component creators it is for totally standard things.  In terms of audit trails, I hope you know that Joomla3.2 has  built in versioning if you choose to take advantage of it in your component.

Comment: @Elin I was using component-creator as a learning tool and to speed up development time but I hadn't really looked into ACL before now which is what had me stumped! The code isnt necessary considering how Im using it. What I ended up doing was overriding the save and postSaveHook functions in the controller to create an entry in an audit table each time the record was changed. Having done that I realised when you said it that I had read about J3.2 versioning but forgot about it so I must take another look at it and see if that provides a more elegant solution that my one! Thanks for the tip!